# Optimal way to filter out records from array of objects depending on the value(s)

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

```
[

 {status: "ABC", groupID: "Group 1"}
 {status: "PQR", groupID: "Group 1"}
 {status: "ABC", groupID: "Group 1"}
 {status: "ABC", groupID: "Group 1"}
 {status: "XYZ", groupID: "Group 1"}

 {status: "ABC", groupID: "Group 2"}
 {status: "ABC", groupID: "Group 2"}
 {status: "ABC", groupID: "Group 2"}

 {status: "ABC", groupID: "Group 3"}
 {status: "PQR", groupID: "Group 3"}

 {status: "XYZ", groupID: "Group 4"}
 {status: "LMN", groupID: "Group 4"}
 {status: "PQR", groupID: "Group 4"}

 {status: "ABC", groupID: "Group 5"}

]
```

Above is an array of objects which have 2 keys each(status & group ID). How to filter out the Group ID's which only have **status ABC** (Group 2 & Group 5 as per above array).

Objects are sorted according to their groupID

This works but doesn't look like an optimal solution because I am unable to omit the entire groupID pack whenever a different status is found(like Group 4 has).

```
jQuery.each(arrObjs,function(k,v){
                var thisStatus = v['status'];
                var thisGroup  = v['groupID'];    
                var grpIndex   = allGroupID.indexOf(thisGroup);

                (grpIndex == -1 && allGroupID.push(thisGroup));

                if(!(thisStatus == 'ABC')){
                    allGroupID.splice(grpIndex, 1);
                }   
             });
```

Result needed:

```
['Group 2','Group 5'] //the Group ID's which have status ABC only, Group 1,3 & 4 dont qualify because they have other status values too.
```

Sorry if this is just an opinion based question.

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Comment: @NinaScholz sorry I had added it in between the question instead of last.. Only those group ID's to be collected who have all the statuses ABC.

Comment: it would be easier to understand if you add the result.

Comment: I have added that now, Only Group 2 & 5 should be the result as they have all statuses ABC. Group 1,3 & 5 wont because they have other values also (XYZ,PQR etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first group them by status into one object and then filter the values based on the desired status using `filter` and `every` methods.

```js
const data = [{"status":"ABC","groupID":"Group 1"},{"status":"PQR","groupID":"Group 1"},{"status":"ABC","groupID":"Group 1"},{"status":"ABC","groupID":"Group 1"},{"status":"XYZ","groupID":"Group 1"},{"status":"ABC","groupID":"Group 2"},{"status":"ABC","groupID":"Group 2"},{"status":"ABC","groupID":"Group 2"},{"status":"ABC","groupID":"Group 3"},{"status":"PQR","groupID":"Group 3"},{"status":"XYZ","groupID":"Group 4"},{"status":"LMN","groupID":"Group 4"},{"status":"PQR","groupID":"Group 4"},{"status":"ABC","groupID":"Group 5"}]

const filterByStatus = (data, status) => {
  const grouped = data.reduce((r, e) => {
    if (!r[e.groupID]) r[e.groupID] = [e]
    else r[e.groupID].push(e)
    return r;
  }, {})

  return Object.values(grouped)
    .filter(a => a.every(e => e.status === status))
    .flat()
}

console.log(filterByStatus(data, 'ABC'))
```

To get an array of just groupID's that all match the status you could use different approach with `Set` to get all unique groupID's and then use filter to get just desired ones.

```js
const data = [{"status":"ABC","groupID":"Group 1"},{"status":"PQR","groupID":"Group 1"},{"status":"ABC","groupID":"Group 1"},{"status":"ABC","groupID":"Group 1"},{"status":"XYZ","groupID":"Group 1"},{"status":"ABC","groupID":"Group 2"},{"status":"ABC","groupID":"Group 2"},{"status":"ABC","groupID":"Group 2"},{"status":"ABC","groupID":"Group 3"},{"status":"PQR","groupID":"Group 3"},{"status":"XYZ","groupID":"Group 4"},{"status":"LMN","groupID":"Group 4"},{"status":"PQR","groupID":"Group 4"},{"status":"ABC","groupID":"Group 5"}]

const filterByStatus = (data, status) => {
  const groups = new Set(data.map(({groupID}) => groupID))
  return [...groups].filter(g => !data.some(e => e.groupID == g && e.status !== status ))
}

console.log(filterByStatus(data, 'ABC'))
```

Comment: Group2 is occurring twice, It should not be repeating

Comment: This has been accepted as an answer but I assume solution posted in the question itself is also equally optimal.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a single loop approach and check the former group and take a variable for keeping and the group array.

If the group is changing, check `keep` and add the grouped items to the result set.

```js
var array = [{ status: "ABC", groupID: "Group 1" }, { status: "PQR", groupID: "Group 1" }, { status: "ABC", groupID: "Group 1" }, { status: "ABC", groupID: "Group 1" }, { status: "XYZ", groupID: "Group 1" }, { status: "ABC", groupID: "Group 2" }, { status: "ABC", groupID: "Group 2" }, { status: "ABC", groupID: "Group 2" }, { status: "ABC", groupID: "Group 3" }, { status: "PQR", groupID: "Group 3" }, { status: "XYZ", groupID: "Group 4" }, { status: "LMN", groupID: "Group 4" }, { status: "PQR", groupID: "Group 4" }, { status: "ABC", groupID: "Group 5" }],
    result = [],
    lastGroupID,
    group = [],
    keepGroup = false;

for (let item of array) {
    if (lastGroupID !== item.groupID) {
        if (keepGroup) result.push(group[0]);
        lastGroupID = item.groupID;
        group = [];
        keepGroup = true;
    }
    if (item.status !== 'ABC') keepGroup = false;
    group.push(item);
}
if (keepGroup) result.push(group[0]);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Would this not iterate over the rest of Group 1 records after 2nd record is reached (status PQR)

Comment: you need still to visit each item, despite of you want the group.

Comment: yea given this structure I think it wont be possible to skip entire group on 1st mismatch.

Comment: Group2 is occurring 3 times in result. Want only once.

Answer (score 1):

You could you use [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). Basically you keep track of the group you want to ignore in order to avoid to add them in the final results:

```
var arr = [
 {status: "ABC", groupID: "Group 1"},
 {status: "PQR", groupID: "Group 1"},
 {status: "ABC", groupID: "Group 1"},
 {status: "ABC", groupID: "Group 1"},
 {status: "XYZ", groupID: "Group 1"},

 {status: "ABC", groupID: "Group 2"},
 {status: "ABC", groupID: "Group 2"},
 {status: "ABC", groupID: "Group 2"},

 {status: "ABC", groupID: "Group 3"},
 {status: "PQR", groupID: "Group 3"},

 {status: "XYZ", groupID: "Group 4"},
 {status: "LMN", groupID: "Group 4"},
 {status: "PQR", groupID: "Group 4"},

 {status: "ABC", groupID: "Group 5"}
];

const filterByStatus = (st, array) => {
  const ignore = new Set();

  return array.reduce((acc, {status, groupID}) => {
    if (status !== st) {
      ignore.add(groupID);
      acc.delete(groupID);
    } else if (!ignore.has(groupID)) {
      acc.add(groupID);
    }
    return acc;    
  }, new Set())
}

filterByStatus("ABC", arr);
```